# javaScript - Disable Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Tags: javascript, math, numbers, rounding, infinity

I created a component to calculate the power of numbers
but the problem is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.
how can I calculate a larger number like 5^200 in my app completely without rounding?

```
Math.pow(5,200) // it loged `infinity`
```

Comment: You can try using a BIGINT library. Or you could, alternatively, do calculations on "strings" with your own algorithms if no other library suffices. If you use a "string" approach, there is no limit other than max string length, on precision.

Comment: Can you use the `BigInt` object? https://betterprogramming.pub/using-javascript-bigint-to-represent-large-numbers-d1ad9f6e0079